# Как удвоить элементы в одноправленном списке? И как найти среднее арифм. СПИСКА?

Tags: c++, список

Вот сама реализация списка целых чисел 3 5 1 9

```
    struct Data

  {   int a;
    };

    struct List
    {   Data d;
    List *next;
    };


    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        List *u = NULL;
        // 1 uzel
        u = new List; // obyavlenie 
        u->d.a = 3;  
        u->next = NULL; // ukazatel na sled element
        // dlya udobstva sozd peremennuyu-ukazatel kotoraya hranit adress posl elementa
        List *x;
        // 2 uzel
        x = u;
        x->next = new List;
        x = x->next;
        x->d.a = 5;
        x->next = NULL;
        // 
        List *c;
        // 3 uzel
        c = x;
        c->next = new List;
        c = c->next;
        c->d.a = 1;
        c->next = NULL;
        //
        List *b;
        // 4 uzel
        b = c;
        b->next = new List;
        b = b->next;
        b->d.a = 9;
        b->next = NULL;
        // Vivod (prosto idem po spisku)
        while(u)
        {
            cout << u->d.a << endl; 
            u = u->next;         
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Среднее арифметическое так:

```
int sum = 0, count = 0;
while(u)
{
    sum += u->d.a; 
    ++count;
}
cout << "Average = " << double(sum)/count << endl;
```

А удвоить - еще проще:

```
while(u)
{
    u->d.a *= 2; 
}
```

Только сохранять надо исходное хначение `u` в какой-то переменной, а то оно при проходе портится.

Comment: а не подскажите, как вывести удвоенный список?

Comment: А вы просто сохраните значение `u` в какую-то переменную, скаэем, `head`, а потом просто перед началом цикла восстанавливайте его из этой переменной. А цикл тот же самый.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: у меня никак не получается( если там пару строчек, и если Вам не сложно пожалуйста помогите вывести удвоенное значение(((